# Local server to serve api requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, server

I am working on an automation project
I have a local server inside adobe cep. It's a node js/express server.
I want to be able to send an API request to that server from a cloud server.
How can I connect my local server to the web so I can run an HTTPS request that will arrive at my local server?

Thank you very much for helping with this

I didn't really know where to start with this, searched online but didn't get any results yet

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is a two steps configuration, you want to call a local server from the cloud, so:

first of all you need to know your IP (if dynamic it may change)
or you want to use a service like dynDNS so you can associate an ip (192.1.2.3) or an URL (http://myLocalserver) that is callable from the web.

Additionally, you need to setup the port forwarding in your rooter configuration so you can connect your local server (localhost:4200 for instance) to http://myLocalserver:4200